# Finding an unknown value in a matrix

Tags: matrices

I've been doing lots of matrices practice today and I've come across this one which I'm finding quite tricky.
$$
 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 5 \\ 
z & -3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
All I'm told is that $A^2$ is a matrix whose entries are all $0$, and I need to find z.
$$
A^2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\  
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So I suppose I need to write out the second matrix and then I need to find a way of getting to k. Would I first be right to find the determinant? 
So 
$$
(A_{11} \times A_{22}) - (A_{12} \times A_{21}) = -9 - 5z
$$

I was wondering how I might bring the second mentioned matrix into my working out, because obviously it is important?

Answer (score 2):

You know that $A^2 = 0$. If $A$ were invertible, you could multiply both sides by the inverse of $A$:
$$
A^{-1} A^2 = A = A^{-1} 0 = 0
$$
but you know that $A \ne 0$, so $A$ has no inverse, thus its determinant must vanish. Which helps you to determine $z$.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining, I appreciate the clear help!

Answer (score 1):

$$\det(A^2)=(\det(A))^2=(-9-5z)^2=0$$
Thus,
$$9+5z=0\Rightarrow z=-\frac95$$

Comment: Thank you for this.

So just to clear up, A and A^2 are two different vectors.  

How do they fit into each other in terms of the determinant of A being squared as above? Are they the same?

I might just be being incredibly stupid but I can't see the link anywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear help!

Comment: GoodDeeds 

May I ask two very simple questions?

Where is the equation above derived from given that A^2 is not A squared, just another matrix?

Also, I can see why it would equal 0 if the equations were the same, but they're not so where does the 0 come from? 

Would it be possible to have a breakdown of the steps above? Many thanks.

Comment: Why is the determinant of A^2 equal to the determinant of A, Squared?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since you are asking why $\det(A^2)=\det(A)^2$, it might be an easier solution to simply compute $A^2$, which is 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 9+5z & 0 \cr 0 & 9+5z\end{pmatrix}.
$$ 
Then $0=A^2=(9+5z)I_2$, hence $z=-9/5$. If you would like to use determinants, then we will need that $\det$ is multiplicative, i.e,
$$
\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)
$$
for all $A,B$.

Comment: Hello, thanks for this. My question states that all of the values for A^2 are 0, so surely it would be 0, 0, 0, 0?

Comment: Yes, it says that all four entries are zero. This is the most direct solution.